# Separate strings and include separating character in one of the returned components

Tags: objective-c, string

Say I have the following string `"Center-World"` and I want to separate this string in two different strings but I want the dash to be part of `"Center"`. With the code below I got a string with `["Center","World"]` and I want something that returns `["Center-","World"]`.

**Here is my code:**

```
NSCharacterSet *stringDelimiters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" :-"]; 
NSArray *cellContentWords = [cell.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:stringDelimiters];
```

Any suggestions?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had need of something like this recently.  I wanted to break up a selector string (ex: `initWithFoo:bar:baz:`) into its various components: (ex: `initWithFoo:`, `bar:`, and `baz:`).  You've found, as did I, that `componentsSeparatedByString:` doesn't quite cut it.  I therefore created an `NSString` category to do what I was looking for:

```
- (NSArray *) selectorComponents {
    NSMutableArray * components = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableString * scratchString = [self mutableCopy];
    while ([scratchString rangeOfString:@":"].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSRange componentRange = NSMakeRange(0, [scratchString rangeOfString:@":"].location+1);
        NSString * component = [scratchString substringWithRange:componentRange];
        [components addObject:component];
        [scratchString replaceCharactersInRange:componentRange withString:@""];
    }
    [scratchString release];
    return components;
}
```

You'll want to change from searching for `@":"` to `@"-"`, but after that it should work as you're expecting.